# How to send data in a JSON format to an HTTP End Point from a custom web page?

Tags: azure-functions-core-tools

I have created a simple custom web page using HTML and JavaScript, that allows a user to select multiple languages of their choice to translate text.

For example, lets say the user chooses English(en-US) and French(fr-FR) and clicks on "Submit". I want to take the user's request, and send that data to an [Azure Logic HTTP End Point][1]  where I have set up my JSON schema to take "languages" property of type "array". The JSON schema is defined on the HTTP Trigger like below :

Answer (score 1):

[image]you can check the network tab in the dev tool and from what i see is that your page is sending the data in json format. however the there is an error on parsing the response body(check out your end point's response).[image]

Comment: Hi, I don't think I am following you. What do suggest that needs to be fixed?

Comment: Hello @Peter the response from your end point is malformed. that why it can not be displayed in this line `console.log('got result:', result)`.

Comment: Hi @alan, so how I go about fixing it? Is that something wrong with my JavaScript?

Comment: No your js is OK but you have to check the backend(the end point).

Comment: what is the response should be? just a confirmation message?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212116/discussion-between-peter-and-alan-jouhar).

Comment: Hi Alan, I have a question: On Form Submit, how do we include Video ID query parameter in the URL for the fetch call? (For e.g: https://jsfiddle.net/peterlearning/03dcxer7/1?id=b67c519778) . So that the web page can extract and include in the request. I am not sure how to apply the "window.location.href"  in my scenario. I tried to follow this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript  but I am not having must success in my case.